# WooCommerce subcategories help

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

New Uploaded Code:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9 sidebar">
                    <div class="list-group products box">
                        <h4>Product Range</h4>
                        <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
                        foreach ( $terms as $term ){
                        $category_name = $term->name;
                        $parent_category_id = $term->term_id;

                        $categories=get_categories(array( 'parent' => $category_id ));
                    $children = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
                                'parent'    => $parent_category_id,
                                'hide_empty' => false
                    ) );
                  foreach( $children as $subcat ){
                        ?>
                        <a href="<?php get_term_link( $subcat->slug, 'product_cat' ); ?>" class="list-group-item"><?php echo $subcat->name; ?></a>
                        <?php } } ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: This is working but not pulling all the sub categories

Comment: if there are no child categories how can I disable showing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9 sidebar">
                        <div class="list-group products box">
                            <h4>Product Range</h4>
                            <?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
                            foreach ( $terms as $term ){
                            $category_name = $term->name;
                            $parent_category_id = $term->term_id;

                            $categories=get_categories(array( 'parent' => $category_id ));
                        $children = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
                                    'parent'    => $parent_category_id,
                                    'hide_empty' => false
                        ) );
                      foreach( $children as $subcat ){
                            ?>

                            <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($subcat->term_id, 'product_cat'); ?>" class="list-group-item"><?php echo $subcat->name; ?></a>
                            <?php } } ?>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $args = array(
      'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
      'hide_empty' => false,
      'parent'   => 0
  );
$product_cat = get_terms( $args );



  foreach ($product_cat as $parent_product_cat)
  {

  echo '
      <ul>
        <li><a href="'.get_term_link($parent_product_cat->term_id).'">'.$parent_product_cat->name.'</a>
        <ul>
          ';
  $child_args = array(
              'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
              'hide_empty' => false,
              'parent'   => $parent_product_cat->term_id
          );
  $child_product_cats = get_terms( $child_args );
  foreach ($child_product_cats as $child_product_cat)
  {
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($child_product_cat->term_id).'">'.$child_product_cat->name.'</a></li>';
  }

  echo '</ul>
      </li>
    </ul>';
  }
```

Comment: thanks for this but i think i will keep using my method above and see if can get that to work